# Got some confusion in list comprehension

Tags: python

Got some confusion as I'm new to python,about list comprehensions in the code ,need explanation about what is happening with subsets in the list comprehension Thanks in Adv

```
def Powerset2(Pset):
    listabc = [[]]
    for x in Pset:
        newsubsets = [subsets + [x] for subsets in listabc] #Explain this line in detail please
        listabc.extend(newsubsets)
    print(listabc)

Powerset2([2,3,4])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does the following:

- for each element x in Pset, it will transforme x in a list one one
  element.
- Then for each element subsets in the listabc, it will take the subset
  and concatenate [x] to it and put it in newsubsets.

For example if [x] is [4] and subsets is `[1, 2, 3]` then newsubsets will be `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

I hope it will help you.